# Injectivity of $X^* \otimes Y^*$ into $B(X\times Y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, tensor-products, tensors

Denote by $X^*$ the algebraic dual of a vector space $X$. Let $B(X\times Y)$ be the bilinear forms.

Define $X^* \times Y^* \to B(X\times Y),\quad (\alpha ,\beta)\mapsto B_{\alpha,\beta}$, where
$$B_{\alpha,\beta}(x,y) := \alpha (x)\beta (y). $$
By invoking the universal property of the tensor product we get a linear
$$X^* \otimes Y^* \to B(X\times Y),\quad u:=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha _k\otimes \beta _k \mapsto B_u. $$
In [Ryan's Tensor products](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781852334376) it suggested that this map is injective, but I don't understand why. Suppose
$$B_u(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha _k(x)\beta _k(y) = 0,\quad (x,y)\in X\times Y.\tag{1} $$
To show the corresponding tensor $u =0$ it would be equivalent to show (Prop. 1.2)
$$\forall s\in X^{**} \forall t\in Y^{**}\ \sum_{k=1}^n s(\alpha _k)t(\beta _k) = 0 $$
or
 $$\forall s\in X^{**} \sum_{k=1}^n s(\alpha _k)\beta _k = 0 \qquad \mbox{or}\qquad \forall t\in Y^{**}\sum_{k=1}^n t(\beta _k)\alpha _k =0. $$
But I don't see how to make use of $(1)$. For instance, taking $s\in X^{**}$ we would have
$$\left (\sum_{k=1}^n s(\alpha _k)\beta _k\right )(y) = \sum_{k=1}^n s(\alpha _k)\beta _k(y) \overset{?}= 0\qquad (y\in Y). $$
The above would hold in finite dimensions, because then $s$ is identified with $x^{**}$ for some $x$ and $x^{**}(\alpha _k) = \alpha _k(x)$ and $(1)$ applies.

The author doesn't explicitly assume finite dimension, but then I have no idea what $s(\alpha _k)$ is.

> Does (1) imply $u=0$ for arbitrary vector spaces $X,Y$ and what is the justification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the $\beta_k's$ if necessary, you can assume without loss of generality that $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent (choose a maximal subset of independent $\alpha_k$'s, write the others as linear combinations of the elements in the subset, regroup terms, and use the bilinearity of the tensor product).

Fixing $y\in Y$, and letting $x$ range over $X$, $(1)$ show that you have a dependance relation $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\beta_k(y) \alpha_k=0$ in $X^*$. By assumption $\beta_k(y)=0$ for all $k$. But this is true for all $y\in Y$, so $\beta_k=0$ for all $k$ and $u=0$.